# Are these conditions sufficient for this integral to be convergent?

Tags: integration, solution-verification

I'm trying to find conditions for the following integral to be convergent
$$\int_0^1(1-s)^{ \alpha } s^{\beta}ds$$
I think they $\alpha>-1$ and $\beta>0$ are enough. I thought this by just limiting $s^{\beta}$ to $(0,1)$ and multiplying by the integral of $\int_0^1(1-s)^{ \alpha }ds$. What do you guys think about it?

Comment: I think $\beta > -1$ and $\alpha > -1$ is enough. There are singularities at $s = 1$ and $s = 0$. So split it as $\int_{0}^{1} = \int_{0}^{1/2} + \int_{1/2}^{1}$ and then use usual results.

Comment: Note that the change in variables $t = 1-s$ results in the integral $$\int_0^1t^{ \alpha } (1-t)^{\beta}dt$$ so in fact the integral is symmetric in $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and the conditions on them for convergence will be the same.